# HTML 5 Notifications are not working locally in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have found the following example for HTML notifications and it worked fine in Chrome and Firefox. After downloading it and trying it locally it does not work in Chrome anymore. Is this expected behaviour (Chrome preventing notifications locally for some reason) or is there any other reason why this is not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>

        <button onclick="notifyMe()">Notify me!</button>

        <script>
        function notifyMe() {
          // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
          if (!("Notification" in window)) {
            alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
          }

          // Let's check if the user is okay to get some notification
          else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
            // If it's okay let's create a notification
            var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
          }

          // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
          // Note, Chrome does not implement the permission static property
          // So we have to check for NOT 'denied' instead of 'default'
          else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
            Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {

              // Whatever the user answers, we make sure we store the information
              if(!('permission' in Notification)) {
                Notification.permission = permission;
              }

              // If the user is okay, let's create a notification
              if (permission === "granted") {
                var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
              }
            });
          }

        }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "local". I found the page working properly when run on a local server but running it using the file path failed.

Comment: As with most things like this, if 'local' means a UNC URL (i.e. `file:///....` in your browser address bar) it won't work as expected. You need to be on a proper http server even if it's just a local instance of IIS or Apache.

Comment: Do web API notifications work in safari? Because I tried the demo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API of the emogotchi and it works but when i try to create my own app (by literally copying the code to test) it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [W3C Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/) what you have looks ok as long as the file is hosted somewhere. Here is a nice [notification repo](https://github.com/girliemac/html5-notifications-webOS-style), with **[live demo](http://girliemac.com/html5-notifications-webOS-style/)**.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does that mean that you can host the javascript file or you have to host the html file and js file? I'd like to test locally.

Comment: doesn't work for me. opera, mac os, do not disturb = off