# Local javascript website (file:///) confuses notification permissions on Chrome, Edge

Tags: javascript, browser, permissions, notifications, local

I'm building a companion website/app for the call center I work at which does a bunch of handy things including tracking breaks, and that's where I'm having issues.

This "site" will be stored as an html file the user keeps on their computer (I can't host it elsewhere for security reasons), and that seems to be the core of the problem as I'm trying to enable desktop alerts.

Here's what I'm using for requesting notification permission:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  if (!Notification) {
    alert('Desktop notifications not available in this browser.');
    return;
  }
  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
});

function notifyMe() {
  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
 else {
    var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {
      body: "Notification",
    });
  }
}
```

...Which I found in another thread here.

Problem is, as a local file, Chrome will never acknowledge it as having permission: I can click "approve" or "block" and nothing happens. If I manually add "file:///*" to Chrome's allowed sites, it will then receive notifications (it won't if I manually add the entire local address, however). Edge will add "file:" to its approved list but this doesn't work and cannot be edited.

I might just be out of luck here, as I want to get notifications working with a single button click for approval in Chrome (and they won't work at all in Edge).

Is there a way to *specify* the address you want the browser to add to the approved list? I can see a number of potential security issues with doing that, but it might be the only thing that will resolve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `Notification`? (Also, if you can't host the file on a local server, using html/javascript for this seems like entirely the wrong approach. Better off using another language and compiling/converting it into an executable.)

Comment: "Notification" displays desktop notifications, but only if the page has been explicitly granted permission to do so.

I realize another language might be better, but I'm using this project to teach myself JS as well as build a tool for increasing efficiency at my job.

Comment: Adding `file:///*` to the list of sites notifcations are allowed for on chrome://settings/content/notifications is the only solution that works for me too; https://stackoverflow.com/a/24492639/7129538 suggests the html file has to be hosted online